# Optimizing a Java server that is using data compression

Tags: java, sockets, stream

For a multi-client server program, I'm utilizing a wrapper for java.util.zip.Inflater and Deflater that I found online. It seems that--because I'm frequently transferring large amounts of data in the form of ImageIcons--using these zipping methods speeds up my program significantly.

One thing I noticed however, while trying to optimize my program, is that the server is under heavy cpu load while transferring data among clients. The culprit is the server spending unnecessary cpu time unzipping objects sent by a client and re-zipping them to send it to other clients.

This crude schematic of mine may explain what is happening more clearly:

[image]

**My question:**

How can I send the raw compressed data that a client sends to the server directly to other clients without decompressing and compressing on the server side?

I'm not at all familiar with IO streams (I only code for a hobby) so I am stuck clueless. Anyone got any good resources that cover this area?

---

Below is the code that I am using on both server and client side to send and receive compressed data.

**Creating a compressor**

```
new ObjectOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(
        new CompressedBlockOutputStream(
            socket.getOutputStream(), 1024)));
```

**Creating a decompressor**

```
new ObjectInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(
        new CompressedBlockInputStream(
            socket.getInputStream())));
```

Code for CompressedBlock(Input/Output)Streams are below

---

Code that I copied from a source described in the license.

**CompressedBlockInputStream.java**

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

/**
 * Input stream that decompresses data.
 *
 * Copyright 2005 - Philip Isenhour - http://javatechniques.com/
 *
 * This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or
 * implied warranty. In no event will the authors be held liable
 * for any damages arising from the use of this software.
 *
 * Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any
 * purpose, including commercial applications, and to alter it and
 * redistribute it freely, subject to the following restrictions:
 *
 *  1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you
 *     must not claim that you wrote the original software. If you
 *     use this software in a product, an acknowledgment in the
 *     product documentation would be appreciated but is not required.
 *
 *  2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and
 *     must not be misrepresented as being the original software.
 *
 *  3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source
 *     distribution.
 *
 * $Id:  1.2 2005/10/26 17:40:19 isenhour Exp $
 */
public class CompressedBlockInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    /**
     * Buffer of compressed data read from the stream
     */
    private byte[] inBuf = null;

    /**
     * Length of data in the input data
     */
    private int inLength = 0;

    /**
     * Buffer of uncompressed data
     */
    private byte[] outBuf = null;

    /**
     * Offset and length of uncompressed data
     */
    private int outOffs = 0;
    private int outLength = 0;

    /**
     * Inflater for decompressing
     */
    private Inflater inflater = null;

    public CompressedBlockInputStream(InputStream is) {
        super(is);
        inflater = new Inflater();
    }

    private void readAndDecompress() throws IOException {
        // Read the length of the compressed block
        int ch1 = in.read();
        int ch2 = in.read();
        int ch3 = in.read();
        int ch4 = in.read();
        if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        inLength = ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));

        ch1 = in.read();
        ch2 = in.read();
        ch3 = in.read();
        ch4 = in.read();
        if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        outLength = ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));

        // Make sure we've got enough space to read the block
        if ((inBuf == null) || (inLength > inBuf.length)) {
            inBuf = new byte[inLength];
        }

        if ((outBuf == null) || (outLength > outBuf.length)) {
            outBuf = new byte[outLength];
        }

        // Read until we're got the entire compressed buffer.
        // read(...) will not necessarily block until all
        // requested data has been read, so we loop until
        // we're done.
        int inOffs = 0;
        while (inOffs < inLength) {
            int inCount = in.read(inBuf, inOffs, inLength - inOffs);
            if (inCount == -1) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            inOffs += inCount;
        }

        inflater.setInput(inBuf, 0, inLength);
        try {
            inflater.inflate(outBuf);
        } catch(DataFormatException dfe) {
            throw new IOException("Data format exception - " + dfe.getMessage());
        }

        // Reset the inflator so we can re-use it for the
        // next block
        inflater.reset();

        outOffs = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (outOffs >= outLength) {
            try {
                readAndDecompress();
            }
            catch(EOFException eof) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return outBuf[outOffs++] & 0xff;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < len) {
            if (outOffs >= outLength) {
                try {
                    // If we've read at least one decompressed
                    // byte and further decompression would
                    // require blocking, return the count.
                    if ((count > 0) && (in.available() == 0))
                        return count;
                    else
                        readAndDecompress();
                } catch(EOFException eof) {
                    if (count == 0)
                        count = -1;
                    return count;
                }
            }

            int toCopy = Math.min(outLength - outOffs, len - count);
            System.arraycopy(outBuf, outOffs, b, off + count, toCopy);
            outOffs += toCopy;
            count += toCopy;
        }

        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        // This isn't precise, but should be an adequate
        // lower bound on the actual amount of available data
        return (outLength - outOffs) + in.available();
    }

}
```

---

Code that I copied from a source described in the license.

**CompressedBlockOutputStream.java**

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

/**
 * Output stream that compresses data. A compressed block
 * is generated and transmitted once a given number of bytes
 * have been written, or when the flush method is invoked.
 *
 * Copyright 2005 - Philip Isenhour - http://javatechniques.com/
 *
 * This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or
 * implied warranty. In no event will the authors be held liable
 * for any damages arising from the use of this software.
 *
 * Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any
 * purpose, including commercial applications, and to alter it and
 * redistribute it freely, subject to the following restrictions:
 *
 *  1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you
 *     must not claim that you wrote the original software. If you
 *     use this software in a product, an acknowledgment in the
 *     product documentation would be appreciated but is not required.
 *
 *  2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and
 *     must not be misrepresented as being the original software.
 *
 *  3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source
 *     distribution.
 *
 * $Id:  1.1 2005/10/26 17:19:05 isenhour Exp $
 */
public class CompressedBlockOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
    /**
     * Buffer for input data
     */
    private byte[] inBuf = null;

    /**
     * Buffer for compressed data to be written
     */
    private byte[] outBuf = null;

    /**
     * Number of bytes in the buffer
     */
    private int len = 0;

    /**
     * Deflater for compressing data
     */
    private Deflater deflater = null;

    /**
     * Constructs a CompressedBlockOutputStream that writes to
     * the given underlying output stream 'os' and sends a compressed
     * block once 'size' byte have been written. The default
     * compression strategy and level are used.
     */
    public CompressedBlockOutputStream(OutputStream os, int size) {
        this(os, size, Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Deflater.DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a CompressedBlockOutputStream that writes to the
     * given underlying output stream 'os' and sends a compressed
     * block once 'size' byte have been written. The compression
     * level and strategy should be specified using the constants
     * defined in java.util.zip.Deflator.
     */
    public CompressedBlockOutputStream(OutputStream os, int size, int level, int strategy) {
        super(os);
        this.inBuf = new byte[size];
        this.outBuf = new byte[size + 64];
        this.deflater = new Deflater(level);
        this.deflater.setStrategy(strategy);
    }

    protected void compressAndSend() throws IOException {
        if (len > 0) {
            deflater.setInput(inBuf, 0, len);
            deflater.finish();
            int size = deflater.deflate(outBuf);

            // Write the size of the compressed data, followed
            // by the size of the uncompressed data
            out.write((size >> 24) & 0xFF);
            out.write((size >> 16) & 0xFF);
            out.write((size >>  8) & 0xFF);
            out.write((size >>  0) & 0xFF);

            out.write((len >> 24) & 0xFF);
            out.write((len >> 16) & 0xFF);
            out.write((len >>  8) & 0xFF);
            out.write((len >>  0) & 0xFF);

            out.write(outBuf, 0, size);
            out.flush();

            len = 0;
            deflater.reset();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        inBuf[len++] = (byte) b;
        if (len == inBuf.length) {
            compressAndSend();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int boff, int blen) throws IOException {
        while ((len + blen) > inBuf.length) {
            int toCopy = inBuf.length - len;
            System.arraycopy(b, boff, inBuf, len, toCopy);
            len += toCopy;
            compressAndSend();
            boff += toCopy;
            blen -= toCopy;
        }
        System.arraycopy(b, boff, inBuf, len, blen);
        len += blen;
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        compressAndSend();
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        compressAndSend();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you compress / decompress one stage too early. You would need some protocol that has e.g. an uncomressed header for routing and a compressed payload. That way your server could examine the uncomrpessed part to do the routing and not touch (decompress/compress) the compressed payload.

Comment: You can replace the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` with normal `InputStream` and `OutputStream` or even `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`

Comment: @Titus Which doesn't change anything about the decompression/compression issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it does, the idea is to not wrap the socket's stream in `CompressedBlockOutputStream` and `CompressedBlockInputStream` streams on the server. I've posted an answer to illustrate that.

Comment: Hey JYun, great question! I replaced all of your html-tags with markdown, because these are easier to maintain, and normally used on stackoverflow. Your question should still look the same. I removed your hello and thanks, because it adds unnesecary noise to the question, when someone visits in the future for direct information.

Comment: try using https://avro.apache.org/ for compressing and decompressing data objects. And just send the objects across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` with normal `InputStream` and `OutputStream` or even `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`

Here is an example:

```
try(InputStream is = socket.getInputStream()){
    byte[] b = new byte[2048];// you can change the buffer's size.
    for(int r = 0; (r = is.read(b))!= -1;){
        for(OutputStream client : clients){
            client.write(b, 0, r);
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will send the raw bytes received by the server to all the clients (without decompressing and compressing again)

Comment: Ok, now I get where you are going. What I suspected was that there is "routing information" inside the compressed data. I mean information for server to know "where to send" the data. My assumption could as well be wrong, of course.